# Modifying channels in an image

Tags: ios, uiimage

How does one modify the colour and alpha channels in an image?

I am able to apply a colour to an image using `CGContextSetRGBFillColor` which creates a weird effect.

How can a colour channel be modified?

Answer (score 2):

You want to create a bitmap (`CGBitmapContextCreate`) and draw your image to it. That will give you access to the image pixels. To change image data, you can then modify the bitmap bytes directly.

If your use case is simple enough, you can use different techniques, e.g. multiple images with transparency, masks...

Also, check out Core Image Filters (`CIFilter`) available on iOS. One of them may be suitable for you use cases.

Comment: Ended up using CIColorCube.